# Loading bar while script runs

Tags: php, jquery, loading

I have a php script which takes about 10 seconds to run because it is pulling in data and storing it in the db, I want to display a loading bar whilst this script is running and then once its done load the page the user is on...has anybody any ideas how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Have a search for something like jquery spinner. While most examples are talking about dealing with AJAX requests, you can use the basic concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first you need to call the script using an Ajax request. All jQuery ajax methods offer function callbacks that are called when the call is completed. You can show the progress bar when you make the request and hide it, when it is finished:

```
$("#MyProgressBar").show();
$("#placeholder").load(myurl, function() {
  $("#MyProgressBar").hide();
});
```

You could also use a plug-in like [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).