# Display a loading bar before the entire page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, loading

I would like to display a loading bar before the entire page is loaded. For now, I'm just using a small delay:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

The page already uses jQuery.

Note: I have tried this, but it didn't work for me: [loading bar while the script runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245294/loading-bar-while-script-runs)

I also tried other solutions. In most cases, the page loads as usual, or the page won't load/display at all.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use a div `#overlay` with your loading info / .gif that will cover all your page:

```
<div id="overlay">
     <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
     Loading...
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   // FADE OUT YOUR OVERLAYING DIV
   $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

---

Here's an example with a **Loading bar**:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

function loadbar() {
  const elOverlay = el("#overlay");
  const elProgress = el("#progress");
  const elProgstat = el("#progstat");
  const images = document.images;
  const tot = images.length;
  let c = 0;
    
  if (tot == 0) return doneLoading();

  function imgLoaded() {
    c += 1;
    const perc = Math.floor(100 / tot * c) + "%";
    elProgress.style.width = perc;
    elProgstat.textContent = `Loading ${perc}`;
    if (c === tot) return doneLoading();
  }

  function doneLoading() {
    elOverlay.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      elOverlay.style.display = "none";
    }, 1200);
  }
  
  [...images].forEach(img => {
    const tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.onload = imgLoaded;
    tmpImg.onerror = imgLoaded;
    tmpImg.src = img.src;
  });
}

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadbar, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font: 200 16px/1 sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-height: 10rem;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: 1s 0.4s;
}

#progress {
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; /* will be increased by JS */
  top: 50%;
}

#progstat {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="progstat"></div>
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/4000x4000/0bf/000/png" alt="Image 1 description">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/4000x4000/f0b/000/png" alt="Image 2 description">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/4000x4000/bf0/000/png" alt="Image 3 description">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no "side effects"? I was remembering .load() wasn't waiting for some elements, like a full load of all images in the page. **Edit:** I wasn't remembering well, it shouldn't have any side effect, [here is an explanation why](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/)

Comment: I realise that this answer is a bit old, but I was wondering if there was a solution that would degrade nicely if the user has javascript disabled? Because currently they'd just end up with a loading gif for a website.

Comment: weird, question with many views but no upvotes on a useful answer

Comment: @arandompenguin if you load the image using script at the beginning that should solve your problem.

Comment: @roko How can show the loading gif until the first page is completely loaded? I have a parallax website and I want to show loading only till my first pages have been fulyloaded.

Comment: @Roko, deleted my last comment as my issue wasn't with the above code. It was a strange conflict with ipad's safari and a plugin I'm using that works on every other tablet but ipad.

Comment: is it possible to replace the images load by scripts or css files ? if i just want to make my loader for wait my home page is ready.

Comment: Why its perfect! I got an error when it  loading in mozilla. console says TypeError: window.runnerWindow is undefined
 

window.runnerWindow.protect.protect({

Comment: Well, i just removed "window.runnerWindow" line and it worked, i think its a issue from jsBin.

Comment: How to make it loading more smooth?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor you can always use jQuery's `$(prog).animate({width: perc});`

Answer (score 25):

## HTML

```
<div class="preload">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUJoe.gif">
</div>

<div class="content">
I would like to display a loading bar before the entire page is loaded. 
</div>
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $(".preload").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(".content").fadeIn(1000);        
    });
});​
```

## CSS

```
.content {display:none;}
.preload { 
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
​
```

## DEMO

Comment: Is it possible to set opacity of white background when page loading? currently it is displaying white background and loader during page loading. I want to display transparent content during loading. Please let me know.

Comment: Also loader is not displaying exactly in center of page. Please help for this too.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you try to load any data in this window this gif will load.

**HTML**

Make a Div

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('https://lkp.dispendik.surabaya.go.id/assets/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Best and easiest solution.

Comment: How to stop loader after specific time? Currently it is not stopping and displaying all the time.

Comment: Same problem. It's looped forever and it can't be stopped.

Comment: use (".loader").show(); and (".loader").hide(); for start and stop

Answer (score 5):

I've recently made a page loader in VanillaJS for a project, just wanted to share it as, all the other answers, are jQuery based. It's a plug and play, one-liner.

```js
let settings={backgroundColor:"#2774ab",filterBrightness:2,timeOnScreen:100},u=document.querySelector("*"),s=document.createElement("style"),a=document.createElement("div"),m="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",g=document.createElementNS(m,"svg"),c=document.createElementNS(m,"circle");document.head.appendChild(s),s.innerHTML="@keyframes swell{to{transform:rotate(360deg)}}",a.setAttribute("style","background-color:"+settings.backgroundColor+";color:"+settings.backgroundColor+";display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;position:fixed;top:0;height:100vh;width:100vw;z-index:2147483647"),document.body.prepend(a),g.setAttribute("style","height:50px;filter:brightness("+settings.filterBrightness+");animation:.3s swell infinite linear"),g.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 100 100"),a.prepend(g),c.setAttribute("cx","50"),c.setAttribute("cy","50"),c.setAttribute("r","35"),c.setAttribute("fill","none"),c.setAttribute("stroke","currentColor"),c.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray","165 57"),c.setAttribute("stroke-width","10"),g.prepend(c),u.style.pointerEvents="none",u.style.userSelect="none",u.style.cursor="wait",window.onload=(()=>{setTimeout(()=>{u.style.pointerEvents="",u.style.userSelect="",u.style.cursor="",a.remove()},settings.timeOnScreen)});
```

### Fundamentals

- Generate a `<script>` element appended to the `<head>` element, containing any required styling.
- Generate a `<div>` element, acting as overlay, prepended to the `<body>` element.
- Generate a `<svg>` element, acting as loader, prepended to the previously generated `<div>` element.
- On `window.onload` self generated elements are automatically removed.

> #### The latest version is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/amarinediary/Vanilla-JS-Pages-Transition-Loader).

### [Demo](https://codepen.io/amarinediary/full/mdrQvGJ)

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

### Settings

```js
let settings = {
    backgroundColor: "#2774ab",
    filterBrightness: 2,
    timeOnScreen: 100
}, //...
```

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `backgroundColor` | Refer to [MDN Web Docs color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) for acceptable values. The [background-color CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) sets the background color of an element. Default to Wordpress deep blue accent [image: #2774ab] `#2774ab` |
| `filterBrightness` | [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number) or [percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage). The brightness of the `svg` loader element ([brightness() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness())). A value under `100%` darkens the loader, while a value over `100%` brightens it. The lacuna value for interpolation is `1`. Default to `2`. |
| `timeOnScreen` | Positive `integer`. The time on screen is appended to the page loading time. Default to `100` milliseconds. |

Answer (score 0):

Semantic UI might also help, with just simple one liner to show and to hide the loading icon.

Eg: `<div class="ui active centered inline loader"></div>`

Source: https://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html

Found a code sample: https://codepen.io/fujiyamayuta/pen/JBxxJO

Although, there is a small typo in the JS file of the above code sample, corrected is shown below:

```
// ** Loader ON
$('#dimmer').dimmer('show');

// ** Loader OFF
// $('#dimmer').dimmer('hide');
```