# Drupal 7: Put a loading screen before everything is loaded

Tags: drupal-7

My Drupal site takes a while to load, and while it's loading everything looks messed up. So I opted for a simple solution that it's using a loading screen with this kind of solution:
[Display a loading bar before the entire page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072759/display-a-loading-bar-before-the-entire-page-is-loaded) .

But I have no idea how to implement it in Drupal 7.
Can you please help me with some clues?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
.ajax-progress-throbber {
    z-index: 1500;
    border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
    position: fixed;
    background: url('loader.gif') no-repeat center #ccc !important;
    opacity:0.6;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
```

I have done like this by putting this code in my css file and used a loader.gif image which is laso in the same folder where my css file is and use that class . Basically i use loader image every time i trigger ajax. You can use it as you want with according to different class.