# How to add time to window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a website loader and have the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function load() {
                window.removeEventListener('load', load, false);               
                document.body.classList.remove('js-loading');
            },
               false);
```

Thanks to this I'm creating a CSS animation with .js-loading class, and when the page is loaded this class is removed. 
To have a smooth finished animation I need add some delay time after that this class will disappear. (website load time + additional delay)
Could you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072759/display-a-loading-bar-before-the-entire-page-is-loaded

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[SetTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)</kbd>:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function load() {
     window.removeEventListener('load', load, false);               
     setTimeout(function(){document.body.classList.remove('js-loading');},2000);

},false);
```

Comment: how did you make that setTimeout button ? :P

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Thats <kbd></kbd> tag :)