# Hiding a form after submit with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide the form and show a loading GIF after submitting it. I've tried many methods and this is one of them. I tried replacing ClassName with Id and it didn't work.

It's a school project. I've spent way too long wondering what I'm doing wrong here and I am not sure what else to try.

The login button says "Kirjaudu".

html:

```
  <div class="user" id="logsection">
      <div class="user__header">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3219/logo.svg" alt="" />
          <h1 class="user__title">Kirjaudu sisään</h1> <!-- kirjaudu sisään = login -->
      </div>

      <form class="form" action="login_users.php" method="post" name="loginform" onsubmit="processing()">
          <div class="form__group">
              <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Käyttäjänimi" class="form__input" required/> <!-- käyttäjänimi = username-->
          </div>

          <div class="form__group">
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Salasana" class="form__input" required/> <!-- salasana = password -->
          </div>

          <button name="add" class="btn-prim" type="submit">Kirjaudu</button> <!-- kirjaudu = login-->
          <button class="btn-sec" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='../register/register.php'">Luo tili</button> <!-- luo tili = sign up -->
      </form>
  </div>
```

js:

```
function processing() {
        document.getElementById('loginsection').style.display = 'none'
       document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block'
      }
```

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-size: 200% 100% !important;
    background: url('../img/login.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
header{
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(#2b2b2b 31%, #1b1b1b 100%);
  opacity: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
header{
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
header p{
  color: #AAAAAA;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
a img{
  margin: 10px;
}

.user {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 340px;
    margin-left: 39%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}

.user__header {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 500px, 0);
    animation: arrive 500ms ease-in-out 0.7s forwards;
}

.user__title {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
}

.form{
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 500px, 0);
    animation: arrive 500ms ease-in-out 0.9s forwards;
}

.form--no {
    animation: NO 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.form__input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: $font-family;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 80%;

    &:focus {
        background: darken(#fff, 3%);
    }
}

.btn-prim {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: $font-family;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
    color: white;
    background: #ABA194;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }
.btn-prim:hover{
    background: #91897d;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-sec {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: $font-family;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn-sec:hover{
    color: #91897d;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.loading{
  background-image: url(../img/loading.gif);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}
@keyframes NO {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes arrive {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 100% 0
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0 0
    }
}
```

php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<?php

   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'kotisivu'); //kotisivu = homepage
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

   session_start();

   $_SESSION['success'] = "";

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db,$_POST['username']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db,$_POST['password']);
      $password = md5($password);

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      if($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        sleep(3);
        header("Location: ../homepage.php");
        exit();

      }else {
        echo '<body>
              <center>
              <h2 style="color:red;margin-top:100px;">Väärä käyttäjänimi ja/tai salasana<br></h2>
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/RedX.svg/1024px-RedX.svg.png" padding-left="50px" width="100px" height="100px"><br>
              </center>
              </body>';                             //Väärä käyttäjänimi ja/tai salasana = Wrong username and/or password
        header( "refresh:2;url=login.php" );
      }
   }
?>

<!-- ========================================================================= -->
```

Comment: Unless you have `var form = 'form'` then `document.getElementByClassName(form);` should be `document.getElementByClassName('form');`

Comment: And aslo `document.getElementByClassName(loading)` should be `document.getElementByClassName('loading')`. You should use the dev tools of your browser to identify your problem.

Comment: Also, a clear example of why we use [tag:jquery] `$(".form,.loading").toggle()` to replace 17 lines of code

Comment: From your edit: *I tried replacing ClassName with Id and it didn't work.* - you probably don't need all that code/html/etc in the question - just include what *does* work and what you did that *doesn't* work - along with the *relevant* HTML.

Comment: eg `getElementByClassName(id)` likely won't work.  Also your `form` (as provided) doesn't have an `id`, so unclear what you did when you *"tried replacing with id"*

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Still not working

Comment: @freedomn-m what i meant is i tried adding an id to the form and used getElementById('id') but it didn't work.

Comment: `var div = document.getElementByClassName('loading');`, and then `if (div.style.display == 'block')`, also makes no sense. `getElementByClassName` does not return a single element, it returns an HTMLCollection. You need to access a specific element in that collection.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing your code, what I could understand is the form is getting submitted and it redirects to "login_users.php" that's the default behavior.

**You have 2 choices here.**

1. Display the loading GIF as pre-loader in "login_users.php" [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072759/display-a-loading-bar-before-the-entire-page-is-loaded)
2. Use ajax call to send user details to php page and while receiving ajax response stop showing loading GIF

Below is a simple example: -

```js
function login(){
   document.getElementsByClassName('myForm')[0].style.display='none';
   document.getElementsByClassName('load')[0].style.display='block';
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="enter_name"/><br/>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="login" onclick="login()"/>
<input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>

<div class="load" style="display:none;text-align:center"><img src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/y1ZBcOGOOtlpC/giphy.gif?cid=790b761183293fb50b01470e2d69f77e553e1069d6c5464c&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g"></div>
```

Comment: Ok i got it working fine. It isn't finding the js file for some reason so I added the code at the bottom of the html code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are giving too much effort to do this simple task. Just try this simple logic:

```
<div id="formSectionID">
    <form onsubmit="processingx()">
       .............
    </form>
</div>
<div id="processingSectionID" style="display:none">
      <img src="processing.gif" height="50">
</div>

<script>
       function processingx() {
        document.getElementById('formSectionID').style.display = 'none'
       document.getElementById('processingSectionID').style.display = 'block'
      }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it still isn't working for me. Could the php having sleep(3); after successful submit have something to do with it? Is there a better way to add delay after submitting the form?

Comment: The function is totally okay and has nothing to do with your PHP code. Check your form action, is it redirecting to a different page? But I would say your PHP coding needs a lot of work to make it better.