# Create loading bar while an other function is executing php

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm using laravel to develop my web application ,and i have a migration function i want to add a loading bar while the function is running then the loading bar is hidden when the function ends how can i do this.

Comment: You should be using jquery / javascript to do that. Use `.show()` of jquery before sending request to the server and then `hide()` after the server finished process.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then edit your question to have a better quality (and upvotes) :] see you around

Answer (score 0):

you can get it from here

http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script

:) or try some other sites 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html
good lucky have fun

Comment: Actually i found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245294/loading-bar-while-script-runs  but i still don't know how to use it with laravel 5

Comment: you can use it in b/w <head> tag <script> $("#MyProgressBar").show();
$("#placeholder").load(myurl, function() {
  $("#MyProgressBar").hide();
}); </script>